# Cypress - Mui: Component not found <MenuItem value={"id":123}>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress, menuitem

I'm trying to apply cypress click on Mui's MenuItem component but it does not seem to happen. It does not find the element in DOM. I'm using `cypress-react-selector` library to select the component.

```
import 'cypress-react-selector';
Cypress.Commands.add('filterSection', (option: any) => {
 cy.react('MenuItem', {props: {value: option}}).click()
}

ERROR:
Component not found <MenuItem value={"id":123}>
```

this is how I call this method

```
cy.filterSection({id: 123});
```

Comment: Do your need to use cypress-react-selector to do the test?

Comment: Yes, I need to use that!